# WEPopOver and MonoTouch (MonoDevelop)

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I have been trying to develop in MonoDevelop for about a week now, my boss asked me to get WEPopOver working on a particular project. I have seen the github documentation and looked at examples, but can't seem to get a working model for MonoDevelop.

Can ANYONE give me an example of how to use this WEPopOver in MonoDevelop?

thank you in advance!
Rick

Comment: It's so nasty when people bring controls that mimic UIPopoverControl to iPhone. Of course, it's OK when it works but careful :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you see/try the [sample](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/WEPopover/sample/WEPopoverSample) solution that comes with the [bindings](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/WEPopover/) ?

If so then you'll need to be more explicit (edit your question) about what you want to do with it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will give it a shot and come back and let you know. Thanks for the link!